# Detecting touch pressure (force) with swift (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So, I've got this game with *Swift* on Xcode where I have a SKShapeNode that jumps. I would like, though, to have this jump commensurated to the touch the player does. Hence, a small tap will get a small jump and a more brisk one gets a higher jump. How is it possible to do this (mind that I do not want any 3D touch options)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this sort of thing in games is done by timing the press and altering the jump height accordingly. (Which is also why using physics in 2D platforming games is tricky for this kind of thing).

The way it is done in games like Super Mario is to have the start of the jump movement begin as soon as the touch is pressed. Then after some amount of time (as the character is half way "up" the jump) you check to see if the touch is still down. If it is you can make the jump animation continue upwards. If the touch is released then start to bring the jump down again.

That way a short touch is a small jump but a longer touch is a higher jump.

If you have a `smallJumpAction` and `bigJumpAction` at the moment then what you could do is break it down into smaller parts...

`beginJumpAction` which is triggered immediately and then... `smallJumpEndAction` and `bigJumpEndAction`.

This could be done with a sequence action...

```
let beginJumpAction = //move the player upwards slightly
let smallJumpEndAction = //begin to move the player down
let bigJumpEndAction = //move the player up a bit more and then move down

let blockAction = SKAction.run {
    if touchStillDown {
        player.runAction(bigJumpEndAction)
    } else {
        player.runActgion(smallJumpEndAction)
    }
}

player.runAction(SKAction.sequence([beginJumpAction, blockAction])
```

Something like this anyway. There are many ways to approach this though :)

Comment: Thank you very much! It was what I was thinking and you perfectly voiced (or *worded* ahah) my thoughts! Thanks!